# A solution for combinations of elements types, when any of the types can have zero elements

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

I have 3 Models/Entities, A,B,C (backend is django).

On front-end I have 3 empty boxes, where I need to add instances of A,B,C.
The number of instances for A,B,C available can be 0 to infinite.

Ideally, I should show 1 of A, 1 of B and 1 of C, but sometimes any of the Entities can have no instances. Can be none, one or multiple with no instances.

My base approach is to use `ifs` but it is not efficient, see just one of the branches in pseudo-code:

```
if not C:
   if A:
      if not B:
         show up to 3 of A if they are available
      elif B:
        if at least 2 of A:
          show 2 of A and 1 Of B
        if 1 of A:
          show 1 of A and up to 2 of B
   elif not A:
      show up to 3 of B if exist
```

Besides being tens of `ifs` on all branches, it doesn't scale, for example if I add a new Entity and/or box in the future.

So, I'm looking for an algorithm that can scale. I'm using Python,django, PostgreSQL. I extract the data, simple:

```
A.objects.all().order_by('-id')[:3]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
models = [A, B, C]
num_boxes = len(models)  # but could be different
objects = [list(model.objects.all().order_by('-id')[:num_boxes])
           for model in models]
boxes = []

while any(objects):
    for row in objects:
        if row:
            boxes.append(row.pop(0))

print(sorted(
    boxes[:num_boxes],
    key=lambda x: models.index(type(x))
))
```

Comment: it is posible to order by type after; it is working but I obtain something like [a, c, a] and I want ['a', 'a', 'c']

Comment: @user3541631 Sure. If you want to order alphabetically by the Django model name you could use `sorted(boxes[:3], key=lambda x: x._meta.model.__name__)`

Comment: I want the index order of the list types (a,b,c are just name placeholders, so just in example are alphabetical)